# Tags field at bottom of this form

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know how to add placeholder text in a form field but have it uneditable. Look at the Tags field below for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems easy enough, use `placeholder` and disable the field:

```
<input type='text' placeholder='see?' disabled />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ScqY8/1/

Comment: Let me clarify, the field can't be disabled or read only. When you click the field and enter text, the placeholder text disappears.

Comment: What?? Now I'm extremely confused. @stevenpepe

Comment: I got it. Just got rid of the disabled and placeholder does it. Thank you.